# In oracle How to use OVER (PARTITION BY ???) AS Count, when group changers , count should reset to 1

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, gaps-and-islands

I have a Oracle table with [row, grp and pdate] columns, I need no of occurrence of [grp] column for each [pdate] ] column , if same [grp] repeated in rest of the rows count should get rest like Expected Results [table 3]

Table data [table 1]

```
ROW    GRP PDATE     
---------------------- 
0001    361  06-MAR-23
0002    361  07-MAR-23
0003    361  08-MAR-23
0004    417  09-MAR-23
0005    361  10-MAR-23
0006    361  11-MAR-23
0007    362  12-MAR-23
0008    361  13-MAR-23
0009    361  14-MAR-23
0010    361  15-MAR-23
0011    361  16-MAR-23
0012    417  17-MAR-23
0013    417  18-MAR-23
0014    362  19-MAR-23
0015    362  20-MAR-23
0016    362  21-MAR-23
```

SQL that isn't working [table 2]

```
select ROW,GRP,PDATE
,count (1) OVER ( PARTITION BY  A.GRP ORDER BY  A.GRP,A.PDATE) AS COUNT
from t2 a ORDER BY PDATE;

ROW_                   GRP_                   PDATE_                    COUNT                  
---------------------- ---------------------- ------------------------- ---------------------- 
48                     361                    06-MAR-23                 1                      
49                     361                    07-MAR-23                 2                      
34                     362                    08-MAR-23                 1                      
50                     361                    08-MAR-23                 3                      
51                     417                    09-MAR-23                 1                      
35                     362                    09-MAR-23                 2                      
52                     361                    10-MAR-23                 4                      
36                     362                    10-MAR-23                 3                      
53                     361                    11-MAR-23                 5                      
40                     388                    12-MAR-23                 1                      
54                     361                    12-MAR-23                 6                      
55                     361                    13-MAR-23                 7                      
41                     388                    13-MAR-23                 2                      
42                     388                    14-MAR-23                 3                      
56                     361                    14-MAR-23                 8                      
43                     388                    15-MAR-23                 4                      
57                     361                    15-MAR-23                 9
```

[table 3]

Expected Results (using Oracle COUNT( 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ??? order by ) AS Count)
Base on no of occurrence GRP in a date)

```
ROW     GRP  PDATE     COUNT                  
---------------------- ------
0001    361  06-MAR-23  3
0002    361  07-MAR-23  3
0003    361  08-MAR-23  3
0004    417  09-MAR-23  1
0005    361  10-MAR-23  2
0006    361  11-MAR-23  2
0007    362  12-MAR-23  1 
0008    361  13-MAR-23  4
0009    361  14-MAR-23  4 
0010    361  15-MAR-23  4
0011    361  16-MAR-23  4
0012    417  17-MAR-23  2
0013    417  18-MAR-23  2 
0014    362  19-MAR-23  3 
0015    362  20-MAR-23  3 
0016    362  21-MAR-23  3
```

Purpose is to create html table with  "colspan" base on result given by the count column

## Example  OUTPUT

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DATE   |   06-MAR-23 (COLSPAN=3)  |  07-MAR-23 COLSPAN=1 |   08-MAR-23 COLSPAN=3   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAA    |    361-1 | 361-2 | 361-3 |         417-1        |    361-1  | 361-2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

After you changed your mind and modified sample table contents, it appears that it is about *islands*, after all. First create "groups" (the `rn` column in my code), then apply `count` function in its analytic form.

```
SQL> with test (row_, grp, pdate) as
  2    (select '0001', 361, date '2023-03-06' from dual union all
  3     select '0002', 361, date '2023-03-07' from dual union all
  4     select '0003', 361, date '2023-03-08' from dual union all
  5     select '0004', 417, date '2023-03-09' from dual union all
  6     select '0005', 361, date '2023-03-10' from dual union all
  7     select '0006', 361, date '2023-03-11' from dual
  8    ),
  9  temp as
 10    (select row_, grp, pdate,
 11       to_number(row_) - row_number() over (partition by grp order by pdate) rn
 12     from test
 13    )
 14  select row_, grp, pdate,
 15    count(*) over (partition by rn) cnt
 16  from temp
 17  order by pdate;

ROW_        GRP PDATE            CNT
---- ---------- --------- ----------
0001        361 06-mar-23          3
0002        361 07-mar-23          3
0003        361 08-mar-23          3
0004        417 09-mar-23          1
0005        361 10-mar-23          2
0006        361 11-mar-23          2

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for yr response, please refer the source data [table 1], its differs to yours,

Comment: Well, yes - now it differs because you modified it. Have a look at edited code, please.

Comment: Sure, that works good; however, I need to test it with real tables to see which one (+MTO) performs best. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT rw,
       grp,
       pdate,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY mn) AS cnt
FROM   table1
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY rw
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS mn
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (same_grp+)
  DEFINE same_grp AS FIRST(grp) = grp
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (RW, GRP, PDATE) AS
SELECT '0001', 361, DATE '2023-03-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0002', 361, DATE '2023-03-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0003', 361, DATE '2023-03-08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0004', 471, DATE '2023-03-09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0005', 361, DATE '2023-03-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0006', 361, DATE '2023-03-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0007', 362, DATE '2023-03-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0008', 361, DATE '2023-03-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0009', 361, DATE '2023-03-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0010', 361, DATE '2023-03-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0011', 361, DATE '2023-03-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0012', 417, DATE '2023-03-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0013', 417, DATE '2023-03-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0014', 362, DATE '2023-03-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0015', 362, DATE '2023-03-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0016', 362, DATE '2023-03-21' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| RW | GRP | PDATE | CNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 361 | 2023-03-06 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 0002 | 361 | 2023-03-07 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 0003 | 361 | 2023-03-08 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 0004 | 471 | 2023-03-09 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 0005 | 361 | 2023-03-10 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 0006 | 361 | 2023-03-11 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 0007 | 362 | 2023-03-12 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 0008 | 361 | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 4 |
| 0011 | 361 | 2023-03-16 00:00:00 | 4 |
| 0010 | 361 | 2023-03-15 00:00:00 | 4 |
| 0009 | 361 | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 4 |
| 0012 | 417 | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 0013 | 417 | 2023-03-18 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 0015 | 362 | 2023-03-20 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 0014 | 362 | 2023-03-19 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 0016 | 362 | 2023-03-21 00:00:00 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xvhjRXrO)

---

In Oracle 11g, you can use:

```sql
SELECT rw, grp, pdate,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY mn) AS cnt
FROM   (
  SELECT rw, grp, pdate,
         SUM(has_changed) OVER (ORDER BY rw) AS mn
  FROM   (
    SELECT rw, grp, pdate,
           CASE LAG(grp) OVER (ORDER BY rw)
           WHEN grp
           THEN 0
           ELSE 1
           END AS has_changed
    FROM   table1
  )
)
```

or

```sql
SELECT rw, grp, pdate,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY grp, mn) AS cnt
FROM   (
  SELECT rw, grp, pdate,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rw) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY rw) AS mn
  FROM   table1
)
ORDER BY rw
```

or:

```sql
SELECT rw, grp, pdate, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY mn) As cnt
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   ( SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rw) AS rn FROM table1 t )
  MODEL
    DIMENSION BY ( rn )
    MEASURES ( rw, grp, pdate, 1 AS mn )
    RULES (
      mn[rn>1] = mn[cv(rn)-1] + CASE WHEN grp[cv(rn)] = grp[cv(rn)-1] THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    )
)
```

The output is the same as using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` in later versions.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/o5LAManQ)

Comment: Much simpler, exact solution I'm searching for,  but I'm stuck with 11g.

Comment: @ChamiJ Updated with Oracle11g solutions.

Comment: All 11g solutions work excellent, the second solution (My Choice) is quite similar to @Littlefoot's, I need to test with real tables to determine which one performs well. Thank you, MTO.